# Loading JSON with json.loads in Python gives JSONDecodeError because of &quot;

Tags: python, json

I am trying to turn a Javascript from a website into a JSON structure with Python's `json.loads()` but it gives a JSONDecodeError. It's because there are objects in the Javascript which are quoted, and when `json.loads()` runs, it turns `&quot;` into a " (double quote), which produces bad JSON.

This is a very small example of the Javascript:

```
{"key":{"hascookie":"yes"}, "cookiestatus":234, "widget":null, "player":"{&quot;source&quot;:true,&quot;country&quot;}"}
```

There is a lot of JSON, and it's minified.
I am loading it like this:

```
j = 'JSON text'
result = json.loads(j)
```

Is the solution prevent the loads() function to unquote the JSON and leave the `&quot;` as is?

Comment: There is no way round this. You *must* make sure you have a valid json string before calling `loads()`

Comment: I see. What I'm trying to do is just extract a few values from that JSON text, I don't really need the JSON itself, it's in a Javascript part of the HTML. The brute force option would be is to iterate over each character, but there are more 51000 characters in one line.

Comment: Your example is valid JSON. I am not sure you gave the correct example. `&quot;` is in the string.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution (if I understand the problem correctly...):

```py
import json

s = '{&quot;source&quot;:true,&quot;country&quot;:&quot;GB&quot;}'

class myEncoder(json.JSONDecoder):
    def decode(self, s):
        s = s.replace('&quot;', '\"')
        return json.JSONDecoder.decode(self, s)
    
decoded = json.loads(s, cls=myEncoder)
print(decoded)
```

Output is correct JSON: `{'source': True, 'country': 'GB'}`

Comment: I went for a different approach: I simply save the Javascript between 2 index positions into a variable like `var = js[123:-500]` and in `var` I use `find(pattern)` to find what I need. Every time I load the page, the Javascript code is a little less/more, so index positions need to be broad enough to get what i need.